# When given I am often returned. What am I?

Tags: riddle

When given I am often returned,

You can be in me or fall out of me,

and I can be won, done, lost, received and held,

I show up at all the good parties,

I may even have gone to one with you,

Is that me on the left?  Well, sort of...

**What am I?**

Comment: Did I hallucinate seeing a version of this question with a line saying something like "when awarded, I am never returned"? I'm sure I did, but this question now doesn't have it and shows no sign of having been edited. Am I going nuts?

Comment: @gareth I saw it too. I don't know how he did that.

Comment: @Gareth It did.  It was edited.  I wasn't sure about that line and it may be more confusing than helpful so I axed it.

Comment: I wonder why I can't see that the edit happened. Maybe very quick edits don't get shown separately, or something.

Comment: (One reason why I asked is that I wondered about the answer Inazuma's now given, and rejected it partly because of that line that isn't there any more. But evidently it's wrong anyway...)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan There's a 5 minute grace period after posting a question/answer where subsequent edits (by the author) aren't included in the revision history, unless there's been another edit by somebody else first.

Comment: Aha! So my guess about quick edits was right. Thanks.

Comment: "When given I am often returned. What am I?"....a fruitcake!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wonder whether perhaps you are

> favo[u]r.

If so, most of the clues are pretty straightforward (I can add explicit explanations if necessary) but "Is that me on the left? Well, sort of ..." probably refers to

> the use of the word to mean a token of affection -- a bit of fabric, a lock of hair, etc. -- which might e.g. be pinned to one's clothes. (On the left side? Maaaybe.)

and the business about parties to

> [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_favor).

Comment: Damn that was fast.  Well done!  Let me polish you up a big +1  ...and I thought this was a fairly hard one...

Comment: For the record though, the "me on the left" thing was referring to what was literally to the left of the riddle on the screen...

Comment: Oh, that's clever!

Comment: How does "I may have even gone to one with you" relate to a favor?

Comment: That's a good question, and I don't have a good answer to it. (Brent, feel free to deprive me of my checkmark if you think it appropriate.) Perhaps the party in question is one that "you" have thrown yourself??

Comment: @EricE that line was just in reference to the line above, meaning 'you may have taken one to a party'

Comment: Fwiw the vote buttons are above the question on the mobile app

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer:

You might be

> Loveeeeee

When given I am often returned,

> Unless this is a very sad ending, I would hope all love is returned

You can be in me or fall out of me,

> In love, fall out of love  - very common phrases

and I can be won, done, lost, received and held,

> Win love, as in winning someone's affections?
>  Doing/making love? 
>  Lost love - (another possibility - a score of 0 in tennis is love, so you may have 'lost')
>  Receive love (self explanatory)
>  Holding love (not sure)

I show up at all the good parties,

**Not sure anymore**

I may even have gone to one with you,

Is that me on the left? Well, sort of...

> The heart is portrayed as being on the left, but only because it's slightly titled to the left.
>  (Thanks Laurel)

Comment: Sorry.  Some good fits but I'm not looking for love.  :) +1 though.

Comment: No worries. I get too excited :P

Comment: ME TOO! ME TOO! ME TOO! :D

Comment: All the good parties have lots of alcohol, and everyone knows what drinking lots of alcohol can lead to.

Comment: @Ghostship Hangovers? /s

Comment: Your heart is on the left.

Answer (score 3):

Its

> Money

When given i am often returned

> As most cases the change is returned.

You can be in me or fall out of

> Well everyone is into money or can easily fall out of money

I can be won, done, lost, received and held

> Self explanatory

I show up at all the good parties

> At good parties there are many expensive things to be seen like jewellery, showpieces,cars and rich people.

I may even have gone to one with you

> Well everyone has

Is that me on the left?

> I think this is related to corruption money or theft as its handled silently with left hand or kept in left pocket thats why the question mark.

Answer (score 0):

How about

> "Favor"

Trickssey Hobbittses...

Comment: You should use spoiler formatting and give explanations when you answer questions.  Correct though.  But Gareth beat you to it.